# C++/CLI type comparison with "is"

Tags: c#, c++-cli

How do I write this line in C++/CLI?

C#:

```
if (object is ISomething)
{

}
```

Comment: You are right - I misread your question - though Hans has given the correct duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my update. Hans link solved my problem. Not sure if I need to explain how I solved my issue.